# std::accumulate vs for loop, raytracing application

Tags: c++, performance, std

This question is based on [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOSirVeP5lo) made with the purpose of reviewing [this project](https://github.com/valerioformato/RTIAW).

In the video, the host is analyzing the project and found out that the following block of code is a cause of performance issues:

```cpp
std::optional<HitRecord> HittableObjectList::Hit(const Ray &r, float t_min, float t_max) const {
    float closest_so_far = t_max;

    return std::accumulate(begin(objects), end(objects), std::optional<HitRecord>{},
        [&](const auto &temp_value, const auto &object) {
            if(auto temp_hit = object -> Hit(r, t_min, closest_so_far); temp_hit) {
                closest_so_far = temp_hit.value().t;
                return temp_hit;
            }

            return temp_value;
    });
}
```

I would assume that the `std::accumulate` function would function similarly to a `for` loop.  Unhappy with the performance hit there (and because, for some reason, the profiler wouldn't profile the lambda code[a limitation, perhaps?]), the reviewer changed the code to this:

```cpp
std::optional<HitRecord> HittableObjectList::Hit(const Ray &r, float t_min, float t_max) const {
    float closest_so_far = t_max;
    std::optional<HitRecord> record{};

    for(size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        const std::shared_ptr<HittableObject> &object = objects[i];

        if(auto temp_hit = object -> Hit(r, t_min, closest_so_far); temp_hit) {
            closest_so_far = temp_hit.value().t;
            record = temp_hit;
        }
    }

    return record;
}
```

With this change the time to completion went from 7 minutes and 30 seconds to 22 seconds.

My questions are:

- Aren't both blocks of code identical? Why does `std::accumulate` give such enormous penalty here?
- Would the performance be better if instead of using `auto`s, using the explicit type?

The reviewer did mention suggestions such as avoiding the use of `std::optional`s and `std:shared_ptr`s here due to the amount of calls made and to execute this code on the GPU instead, but for now I'm only interested in those points mentioned earlier.

Comment: How is `HitRecord` defined? Since you're taking `temp_value` by reference in the first snippet, you're probably forcing a copy constructor call on every `return temp_value;`. If you accept `temp_value` by value instead, that copy could become a move, or be possibly be elided altogether.

Comment: This is one of the cases where less is more. Even if you end up understanding and fixing the issue to use a standard algorithm, the hot potato will be left for the next unfortunate intern that's tasked to change something in it. I'd go for clarity and keep the reviewer's suggested changes.

Comment: This is one of those (increasing) circumstances where you can't see what is behind a convenience function. `std::accumulate` is a convenience feature that relieves you from looping over the elements, columns, etc.. to save you from implementing a way to iterate over them from scratch. The problem however is you can't see under the hood of `std::accumulate`. Now I'm not saying not to use the convenience function to avoid implementing a `for` loop, etc.., but don't be surprised if you find a hot-spot created due to some unanticipated way the convenience was implemented.

Comment: `for(size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)` use a range loop. `Aren't both blocks of code identical?` -> `record = temp_hit;` shouldn't this be `record = record + temp_hit;`?  `Would the performance be better if instead of using autos, using the explicit type?` Och that's one easy! No, it would not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Desclaimer:** I did not run advanced tests, this is just my analysis based on the video and the code.

From what I see in the profiling in the video, the hotspot in accumulate is here:

```
_Val = _Reduce_op(_Val, *_UFirst);
```

Since `_Reduce_op` is just our lambda, and the profiling shows this lambda is not the bottleneck, then it means the only expensive operation here is the copy assignment operator `=`.

Looking at `HitRecord`:

```
struct HitRecord {
  point3 p;
  vec3 normal;
  std::shared_ptr<Material> mat_ptr;
  float t;
  bool front_face;
  ...
```

We see there is a bunch of stuff including a `shared_ptr`. Chances are the optimizer would remove the copy when it is not needed if the `shared_ptr` was not here. Copying a `shared_ptr` is *relatevely* expensive in a hot loop because it involves atomic operations.

Note that in the profiled `accumulate` code, we see that they tried to fix this in c++20 by introducing a move.

```
#if _HAS_CXX20
        _Val = _Reduce_op(_STD move(_Val), *_UFirst);
#else // ^^^ _HAS_CXX20 ^^^ // vvv !_HAS_CXX20 vvv
        _Val = _Reduce_op(_Val, *_UFirst);
#endif // _HAS_CXX20
```

Though for this move to work, the compiler would have to properly use the named return value optimization which it does not always do when there are multiple return in a function. You would also have to change the signature of the lambda so that it takes a value or an r-value instead of a reference. Changing from auto to a named type would not fix the issue.